# How to add two cells in excel whose values are separated by a slash?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these values in an excel sheet: A1: 6/15, B1:10/3.

I want to add these cells. I used the following formula, but it doesn't work:

```
=LEFT (A1, 1) + LEFT(B1, 1) + LEFT (B1, 2)&"/"&RIGHT (A1, 1) +
     RIGHT (A1, 2) + RIGHT (B1, 1)
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong? How should I change the formula to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula, which isolates and then divides the numbers on either side of the slash:

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("/",A1,1)-1) / RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - SEARCH("/", A1, 1))
```

If you also want a higher level summation or product of multiple such cells, then just use the above formula and then add those cells.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:B1,SEARCH("/",A1:B1)-1)*1)&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(REPLACE(A1:B1,1,SEARCH("/",A1:B1),"")*1)
```

[image]